# TF Implementation of Fast-Rcnn. Why can't I get the same result as caffe?

Tags: tensorflow, caffe, conv-neural-network, face-detection, pycaffe

I am trying to reimplement on tensorflow the [Fast-Rcnn](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.08083) network that is already [implemented in caffe](https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn), in order to use in Face/License Plates detection.

For that purpose, I converted the caffe weights into npy thanks using [this script](https://github.com/SamyMe/tensorflow-fast-rcnn/blob/master/utils/caffe_to_npy.py).

Here is how I present [my model](https://github.com/SamyMe/tensorflow-fast-rcnn/blob/master/models/mono_graph.py). To which I load the converted weights.

PS: I used the roi_pooling implementation by [zplizzi](https://github.com/zplizzi/tensorflow-fast-rcnn).

Does anyone have any idea why I wouldn't get the same result testing same images with same Selective Search bboxes ? I was thinking it might be the flattening process that could differs from caffe to TF, maybe ?

*Edit:

Here is an example of results I get in caffe. While I get no car detection in TF.

[image]

Comment: what percentage of accuracy are you getting?note that accuray shouldnt be the same because of data shuffling ,but it should be close enough with a difference of (around 3%) ,can try to see without shuffing ?cant access your model file from the link

Comment: Actually I test detections in example images and see how both implems (caffe and TF) behave. (I just added an image.)

Comment: it would be better if you could post the code....you see...we can`t make the right guess if we can't see your code...so post your caffe training model...and or Tf training model or attack file links

Comment: I linked to the code in my post: 

My model : https://github.com/SamyMe/tensorflow-fast-rcnn/blob/master/models/mono_graph.py

How I did the weights conversion caffe-tf : https://github.com/SamyMe/tensorflow-fast-rcnn/blob/master/utils/caffe_to_npy.py

Roi_pooling implementation I used : https://github.com/zplizzi/tensorflow-fast-rcnn

Original Caffe implemenentation : https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn/tree/master/models/VGG16

Comment: i can't access these links...logout of github and see if you can also access them without logging in... i am logged in btw

Comment: Oh ! I'm sorry ! There you go.